# butane extraction (microbials)

Tags: organic-chemistry

I was wanting to know using a butane extraction method for hemp flower (cannabis sativa) would also extract the microbial DNA present on the flower as well as deriving the cannabis oil (oleoresin)? This extraction process is used to obtain oleoresin(hash) from flower and I want to know if microbial DNA (or living microbes) can also be extracted? The goal of the extraction is to obviously have no microbes present in the end (this is for human consumption). If someone could explain the chemistry as to why it does or doesn't work I would appreciate it.

Thanks,

Kelsey

Comment: Are you asking whether a DNA extraction method would yield microbial DNA as well as plant DNA? Could you edit your question and give more detail on the goal of the extraction, and the method of extraction?

Comment: @KarstenTheis yes that's exactly what I am wanting to know. I edited it in my question if that helps? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

**DNA contamination**

DNA is water-soluble and non-volatile (large molecules). You would not expect it to be present in a butane extract. However, traces of DNA are difficult to remove. If you look for DNA (using PCR, for example), you will probably find it. After all, it is a forensic molecule of choice.

**Contamination with living microbes**

I don't think living cell would survive the extraction. Fungal spores might, though.

**Human consumption**

There are lots of legal foods where the presence of microbes is desired - yoghurt, beer, cheese are just some examples. All fresh food has its share of microbes, and healthy humans have them too - on the skin and in our digestive tract. Many of these microbes have a role in keeping us healthy, but some make us sick.

As the laws concerning your project differ with location, and the opinions on benefits and risks of your product range widely, I won't comment on those except to say that residual butane would concern me more than traces of microbial DNA.